# Overrepresented Features in Clustering

Tags: clustering, feature-selection

So I was thinking, if I have a set of features (let's say $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$) that basically describe the same overarching feature $Y$, and can somehow be mapped $(X_1, X_2, X_3) \rightarrow Y$. In addition, there exists a forth feature $X_4$ which is not part of this mapping but still contains meaningful data and is conceptually is on the same level as $Y$, meaning $X_4 \rightarrow X_4$.

To relate this to a more tangible example, $(Height, Muscle Density, Weight) \rightarrow Gender$ and the additional independent feature $HairColor$. 
Furthermore, let's assume that $HairColor$ can somehow be meaningful represented as a continuous variable, all features are normalized properly and I don't want to apply factor analysis.

Now, I want to explore this dataset with 4 features $(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4)$, meaning I want to cluster. The majority of cluster algorithms (if not even all) intrinsically rely on distance metrics. This leads me to my first question:

1) The features mapping to $Y$ will account for the majority of distances between observations within my dataset and the distances of $X_4$ between observations will become negligible. This ***probably*** results in two clusters (or in our contemporary age maybe more), namely *male* and *female*. Information about the hair color will get lost.
Is this interpretation/claim (at least in some circumstances) correct?

2) And if so, how would one express/prove this in a formal way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That is just the usual feature weighting problem.

Instead of assuming hair color to be continuous, consider a variable such as income. It's probably on the range of 1:100000, and thus will dominate the other three variables...

If you want to study this more formally, begin with a model where the differences in each variable is composed of signal $w_i$ and error $\epsilon_i$ and then study how much effect each variable has. Use Manhattan distance, as this is easiest to handle.

Comment: Isn´t that the reason why you standardize your variables? My question was targeting every $L^q$ distance. My idea currently is to use cosine similarity instead of $L^q$ metrics.

Comment: Standardization is a hack. It creates as many problems as it solves when you have correlated variables or useless variables. Which you can see from the very same considerations... If you have a duplicate variable and standardize everything, that variable gets twice the weight, for example.